# Swift: How to get weekday from nsdate

Tags: swift, nsdate

Im trying to make a calendar view within the app, one item i need to know is the Int value that the first day of the month falls on. So i can render the rest properly.

I have the following code

```
var CurrentDisplayDate      = NSDate()
var calendar                = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let DateComponents      = calendar.components([.Hour, .Month, .Year, .Weekday], fromDate: CurrentDisplayDate)
let StartWeekDay        = DateComponents.weekday
```

However it keeps giving me the weekday for the current day not the first of the month.

Thanks

Comment: is `CurrentDisplayDate` equal to the current day or the first of the month?

Comment: It will give weekday of current date because NSDate() means **current date (19/05/2016)**.If you want first of the month's weekday,keep the current month and year as it is and change the date to 1 that is **(1/05/2016)**.It will produce weekday of 1st of current month.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this...

```
var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let today = NSDate()
let dateComponents = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: today)
dateComponents.day = 1 // ** set the day of month to 1
// Get a real date back from the modified components
if let startDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents) {
    // and extract the weekday from *that* date
    let startComponents = calendar.components([.Weekday, .Month, .Year], fromDate: startDate)
    let startWeekDay = startComponents.weekday
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let date = NSDate()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)

let month = components.month
let year = components.year

let startOfMonth = ("\(year)-\(month)-01")
print(startOfMonth)
```

You can do it in another way also

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let date = NSDate()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: date)
    let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth))
```